# terraform var output to pick from a map element in list of maps

Tags: terraform

I have an output like this:

```
output "esxi_gw_ip" {
  value = "${packet_device.esxi.network}"
}
```

and the result is this:

```
       "outputs": {
                "esxi_gw_ip": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "list",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "address": "139.0.0.2",
                            "cidr": "29",
                            "family": "4",
                            "gateway": "139.0.0.1",
                            "public": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "address": "blah",
                            "cidr": "127",
                            "family": "6",
                            "gateway": "blah",
                            "public": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "address": "10.88.94.2",
                            "cidr": "29",
                            "family": "4",
                            "gateway": "10.88.94.1",
                            "public": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

I want to get the gateway from `family = 4` and `public = 1`...how can I do that? I can get the first from the list like this and then use something like `jq` in `local-exec`:

```
output "esxi_gw_ip" {
  value = "${packet_device.esxi.network[0]}"
}
```

but that doesn't have any guarantees that it'll always being `0` and I'm also trying to do this natively in terraform vs using shell...

Answer (score 3):

solved my question! if anyone is interested..here is how I did it....in main.tf I added this:

```
data "template_file" "packet_gw_public" {
  count    = "${length(packet_device.esxi.network)}"
  template = "${lookup(packet_device.esxi.network[count.index], "public") == 1 && lookup(packet_device.esxi.network[count.index], "family") == "4" ? lookup(packet_device.esxi.network[count.index], "gateway") : "" }"
}
```

then in output.tf I added this:

```
output "esxi_gw_ip" {
  value = "${element(compact(data.template_file.packet_gw_public.*.rendered),0)}"
}
```